# Unbounded CkEditor5 view values

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am currently trying to build a color plugin for CkEditor5 to mimic the one that was available for CkEditor4.

I have an input method, but mapping the model values to view values is my stumbling block. The System appears to be set up so that every possible value is known in advance and mapped - which for hex values is obviously impractical.

Is there any way to tell CkEditor to just directly use the model value in the view style tag and the view value in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are creating a plugin with a colorpicker UI.

You won't be able to couple that with the existing highlight plugin available for CKE5. Instead, I recommend creating a new plugin. You may check out highlight plugin to see what needs to be done to provide a plugin.

> Is there any way to tell CKEditor to just directly use the model value in the view style tag and the view value in the model?

Yes. You need to set up a proper downcast (model->view) and upcast (view->model) conversion. For that you will need to provide a function which will generate a model/view element.

See docs for [`downcastAttributeToElement`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_downcast-converters.html#static-function-downcastAttributeToElement) and [`upcastElementToAttribute()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_upcast-converters.html#static-function-upcastElementToAttribute). In those docs, there are examples of how to set up a conversion that uses `style` attribute value. Upcast converter shows a more complicated example but you can simply return the value from view.

To add such converter you need to use [`model.Conversion#for..#add` construction](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_conversion-Conversion.html#function-for):

- `editor.conversion.for( 'downcast' ).add( downcastAttributeToElement( downcastConfig ) )`
- `editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' ).add( upcastElementToAttribute( upcastConfig ) )`

Comment: I did have a look at the downcastAttributeToElement, but they have finite states. I.e. 'blue' maps to style: blue. I need to enumerate all possible color values, which is of course near-impossible if I want to allow all hex codes.

Comment: You can provide functions that use any value and convert to any value. See examples in docs.

Comment: I went looking for such examples but couldn't find them. Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Sora2455 - Check the last example from the linked `downcastAttributeToElement()` docs. It's exactly what you want. It takes model value in arrow function to return a view element with `writer.createAttributeElement()` method.

Comment: Yes. I'll just add that the `name` property there says from which elements the attribute will be taken, so it means that `color` attribute on text nodes will be used. I think that you may go simply with `model: 'color'` or whatever attribute name you use in model.

Comment: @jodator So it does. Thank you both!